# Result not shown with this function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the following function to fetch some `RSS` feeds data.

It's interesting because both alerts at the end of script will shown but the result not append to it's div via `jQuery::append()`, I have to mentioned that the passed ID to append function is completely correct.

```
    function generateTopNews() {
        // Manage RSS url
        var targetsURLs = new Array("http://www.jamejamonline.ir/rssfeed?code=01-10-95", "http://www.khorasannews.com/RSS.aspx?type=1", "http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/rss/1", "http://www.varzesh3.com/rss/");
        var logoURLs = new Array("images/jm_logo.png", "images/kh_logo.png", "images/tb_logo.png", "images/v3_logo.png");
        // Temp variables
        var resultArray = new Array();
        var rssCounter = 0;
        // RSS Loader
        for (var i = 0; i < targetsURLs.length; i++) {
            $.ajax({
                url:  "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=" + encodeURIComponent(targetsURLs[i]),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    var fetchedFeed = data.responseData.feed.entries;
                    for (var j = 0; j < fetchedFeed.length && j < 2; j++) {
                            // RSS HTML Template
                            var htmlContent = "<div class=\"col-md-4 col-sm-6\">";
                            htmlContent += "    <div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
                            htmlContent += "        <div class=\"panel-heading\">";
                            htmlContent += "            <img class=\"pull-left\" src=\"" + logoURLs[i] + "\" height=\"23px\" />";     
                            htmlContent += "            <p>" +  fetchedFeed[j].title + "<p>";     
                            htmlContent += "        </div>";
                            htmlContent += "        <div class=\"panel-body\">";                    
                            htmlContent +=              fetchedFeed[j].contentSnippet;
                            htmlContent += "       </div>";
                            htmlContent += "    </div>";
                            htmlContent += "</div>";
                            // Count up the RSS
                            resultArray[rssCounter++] = htmlContent;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        // Start
        $("#rss-container").append("@Start");
        alert("@Start");
        // Append the results
        for (var i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
            $("#rss-container").append(resultArray[i]);
        }
        // End
        $("#rss-container").append("@End");
        alert("@End");
    }
```

Comment: What steps did you already take to debug your page? Did you identify the problem? No? Then please try the best you can and not ask others to debug for you.

Comment: @Andrey I already debug it, I just don't know that why the append function not print anything!

Comment: if you put 1 breakpoint/console.log before your `append` and the line where resultArray is populated you would figure out the problem very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Since ajax is asynchronous, You should write the code for `append()` inside the success event. Otherwise `append()` happen before the data getting fetched from the server.

```
function generateTopNews() {
      // Manage RSS url
      var targetsURLs = new Array("http://www.jamejamonline.ir/rssfeed?code=01-10-95", "http://www.khorasannews.com/RSS.aspx?type=1", "http://www.tabnak.ir/fa/rss/1", "http://www.varzesh3.com/rss/");
      var logoURLs = new Array("images/jm_logo.png", "images/kh_logo.png", "images/tb_logo.png", "images/v3_logo.png");
      // Temp variables
      var resultArray = new Array();
      var rssCounter = 0;
      // RSS Loader
      for (var i = 0; i < targetsURLs.length; i++) {
          $.ajax({
              url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=" + encodeURIComponent(targetsURLs[i]),
              dataType: "json",
              success: function (data) {
                  var fetchedFeed = data.responseData.feed.entries;
                  for (var j = 0; j < fetchedFeed.length && j < 2; j++) {
                      // RSS HTML Template
                      var htmlContent = "<div class=\"col-md-4 col-sm-6\">";
                      htmlContent += "    <div class=\"panel panel-default\">";
                      htmlContent += "        <div class=\"panel-heading\">";
                      htmlContent += "            <img class=\"pull-left\" src=\"" + logoURLs[i] + "\" height=\"23px\" />";
                      htmlContent += "            <p>" + fetchedFeed[j].title + "<p>";
                      htmlContent += "        </div>";
                      htmlContent += "        <div class=\"panel-body\">";
                      htmlContent += fetchedFeed[j].contentSnippet;
                      htmlContent += "       </div>";
                      htmlContent += "    </div>";
                      htmlContent += "</div>";
                      // Count up the RSS
                      $("#rss-container").append(htmlContent);
                  }
              }
          });
      }

  }
```